# bash condition expression

Tags: bash

```
[[ -n "$aOutputFolder" ]] && ( IsEndWithSlash $aOutputFolder || aOutputFolder=$aOutputFolder"/" )
```

the code above is to: check if aOutputFolder is empty; if not, it will check weather it's end with '/' or append a '/'.

When i execute this line with aOutputFold="/home/todd", it didn't append '/' as i expected. Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parens open a new subshell, and the variable is modified in there; the change never happens in the parent shell.

```
[[ -n $aOutputFolder ]] && { IsEndWithSlash "$aOutputFolder" || aOutputFolder="$aOutputFolder/" ; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you provide more information about {} and ()?

Comment: `(...)` runs the command sequence inside in a new subshell (process). `{... ; }` runs the command sequence inside in the same shell if possible (backgrounding and piping can interfere with this).

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try (no need for the `IsEndWithSlash` utility):

```
[[ ${aOutputFolder:-/} != */ ]] && aOutputFolder+=/
```

Explanation:

- `${aOutputFolder:-/}` - If the variable is empty (null or unset), use a slash for the comparison string, otherwise use its value
- `!= */` - If the comparison string is not equal to any sequence of characters ending with a slash
- `&& aOutputFolder+=/` - Then concatenate a slash on the end

Answer (score 0):

You should try: `aOutputFolder+="/"`